# CALayer's image not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to use CALayer to display an image, but the image is not showing up. I've verified that 'image' is not nil, image.size is correct, and layer.contents is a valid CABackingStore.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
  UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"];
  layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
  layer.position = self.view.center;
  layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;

  [layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 5):

Removing `[layer setNeedsDisplay];` should correct the behavior.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/setNeedsDisplay) (emphasis added):

> Calling this method causes the layer to recache its content. This results in the layer potentially calling either the displayLayer: or drawLayer:inContext: method of its delegate. **The existing content in the layer’s contents property is removed to make way for the new content.**

Answer (score 0):

### either use this

```
layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
  [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];

  //UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"];
  layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300,300);
  layer.position = self.view.center;
  //layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
    layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"download.jpeg"].CGImage;
    [layer setNeedsDisplay];
```

### or

remove     `[layer setNeedsDisplay];`
I guess the setNeedsDisplay made the layer to redraw the content and so deleting the image.

--